# How to initialize a class to set custom parameter values using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters, initialization

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to initialize my class. In my case I need to set `params[:name] ||= {}` every time I use that class.

**How to do that?**

---

**UPDATE I**

Is it possible to simplify things using something like

```
class A
  def initialize
    params[:name] ||= {}
  end
end
```

**?**

---

**UPDATE II**

*I forgot* to say that in my class I have to use that parameter as an hash:

```
class A
  def initialize
    # code to initialize params[:name] ||= {}
  end

  def action_name
    params[:name][:ronda] = "Jack"
  end
end
```

If I try to set `params[:name][:ronda]` without inizialize `params[:name] ||= {}`, I get an error. For this I have to initialize the class.

I the above code I can do

```
  def action_name
    params[:name] ||= {}
    params[:name][:ronda] = "Jack"
  end
```

and it will work, but **since I have to use that for every action in the class, I would like to refractor code setting the `params[:name]` at once.**

Comment: Are you looking for something different than `def initialize`?

Comment: I think of no, but I don't know how to initialize a class at all. Where can I find documentation about?

Comment: You can't just do params[:name] without initializing the variable params first. Pan's answer is probably closer to what you'll want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the initialize function to set defaults:

```
class A
  def initialize
    @params = {name: {}}
  end

  def params
    @params
  end
end

A.new.params # {:name => {}}
```

You can also default upon access this way:

```
class A
  def initialize
    @params = {}
  end

  def params
    @params[:name] ||= {}
    @params
  end
end

A.new.params # {:name => {}}
```

The difference is that the first example adds the :name parameter upon creation (A.new) while the second example adds it upon access (A.new.params).

Comment: My solution is still applicable. You need to have params initialized to {} before you can set name. Initializing a class is equivalent to calling .new on it.

Comment: My answer still works. Just use the first example or modify it slightly so that it fits your use case.  The idea is still the same. Either put initialization code into initialize or into the parameter accessor. Pick one that fits your needs and use that.

Comment: In order to have less code as possible, there is a way to simplify things using something like in "UPDATE I"?

Comment: No, not really. You could write this though on a single line if you prefer: 'params = {} and params[:name] = {}' but this is definitely not any simpler than 'params = {name: {}}'. If you are in an initialize function, don't use ||= unless you are passing parameters to the function - it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
@params = {
    :name => {
        :ronda => {}
    }
}
```

in initialize.